# Mongo NamespaceHandler not found when app packaged as single jar

Tags: spring, mongodb

I have a simple spring console app depending on spring-data-mongodb. The app runs fine when I execute the main method via Eclipse (Run As -> Java Application), however when I package as a single jar I got

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo]
```

To create the single jar I used maven assembly plugin

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <descriptorRefs>
      <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
    </descriptorRefs>
    <archive>
      <manifest>
        <mainClass>au.com.myapp.MainClass</mainClass>
      </manifest>
    </archive>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And maven command

```
mvn clean package assembly:single
```

I've checked all the maven dependencies classes inside spring-data-mongodb jar is copied alright including spring-mongo.xsd. I've also tried using `-cp .` and adding spring-data-mongodb.jar alongside my single jar but that doesn't work

How do I fix this problem / is there anything else I can do to debug it

Answer (score 0):

This problem happened because when "uber jar" is created using assembly plugin the contents of META-INF folder for each dependency jar overlaps each other.

For instance spring-data-mongodb has META-INF/spring.handlers file which declares the namespace handler, and in my case it got overwritten by another spring jar

From this fact I've concluded using assembly plugin to create an uber jar isn't really a good approach. Hence I used the original application jar and placed all of its dependencies on a separate folders

This can be achieved with maven by using maven-dependency-plugin like below. All dependencies will get copied to target/dependency (by default binds into process-resources phase)

```
  <!-- Copy all dependencies (including transitive) into target/dependency folder -->
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Then on the command line I run my app by using `-cp` parameter (Windows)

```
java -cp "myapp.jar;dependency/*" com.mycompany.MainClass
```

The downsite is ofcourse I have to delete and re-copy the whole dependency folder when deploying into production server to avoid runtime dependency mismatch